# How to find the row of specific Month and Year in the Column

Tags: vba, excel

I have the small issue, the below `pay out date` column having date format `dd/mm/yyyy`. in that i want to find the row of specific month and Year - example which row containing 10-2017.

```
Pay out Date
12-05-2016
18-05-2016
22-06-2016
20-07-2016
24-08-2016
21-09-2016
19-10-2016
23-11-2016
21-12-2016
18-01-2017
22-02-2017
22-03-2017
19-04-2017
24-05-2017
21-06-2017
19-07-2017
23-08-2017
20-09-2017
18-10-2017
22-11-2017
20-12-2017
24-01-2018
21-02-2018
24-03-2018
```

In normal excel Ctrl+F and giving month and year (10-2017) exactly found which row it is but via code doesn't working - any suggestion would be appreciated

```
Sub find()
Dim c1 As Range
Dim cd As Long
 Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A60").find(What:="10-2017", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

cd = c.Row

  Debug.Print (cd)

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA will be seeing these as a long format not the date format that you see in the sheet. You'll need to account for this in your code

Comment: @Tom hi when i press Ctrl +F giving the month and year its found the row - now what i have to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will look for the date contained in a month

```
Public Sub FindDateInRange()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dat As String
    Dim begMonth As Long, endMonth As Long
    Dim c

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A60")

    dat = "10-2017"

    begMonth = DateSerial(Split(dat, "-")(1), Split(dat, "-")(0), 1)
    endMonth = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(begMonth, 0)

    For Each c In rng
        If c.Value2 >= begMonth And c.Value2 <= endMonth Then
            Debug.Print c.Row
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```